# How to Achieve Translate Animation in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am trying to achieve translate animation in Jetpack compose but i am not able to find Suitable Source for this.Can any one Help me to achieve translate Animation in jetpack compose in which i can set start and edning positionl Manually..

Comment: How do you define "position" here? In relation to other composables or using a global Offset? Please specify your exact requirements.

Comment: Actually i am trying to animate a view from a X start position to Y Position with animation..

Comment: actually i have achieved this using transition animation but i cannot specify start position for it...

Comment: Post the code that you've already have.

Comment: Could you please refer me to some article etc

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The alternative of translate animation in jetpack compose is OFFSET ANIMATION
yes, I was able to achieve this through offset animation.I am sharing the code below with comments in detail so it will be easier for the reader to understand it

```
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
val offsetX = remember { Animatable(0f) }
val offsetY = remember { Animatable(0f) }

Image(
    painter = rememberDrawablePainter(
        ContextCompat.getDrawable(
            context,
            R.drawable.image
        )
    ),
    contentDescription = "image", 
    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
    modifier = Modifier
        .offset {
            IntOffset(
                offsetX.value.toInt(),
                offsetY.value.toInt()
            )
        }
        .width(300.dp)
        .height(300.dp)
)

// Finally run the animation on clicking a button or whenever you want to start it.
coroutineScope.launch {
    launch {
        offsetXFirst.animateTo(
            targetValue = targetValue,
            animationSpec = tween(
                durationMillis = 2000,
                delayMillis = 0
            )
        )
    }

    launch {
        offsetYFirst.animateTo(
            targetValue = size.height.toFloat(),
            animationSpec = tween(
                durationMillis = 2000,
                delayMillis = 0
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to show/hide some composable with translate animation, the best way is to use `AnimatedVisibility`:

```
AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = isVisible,
        enter = slideInVertically { it },
        exit = slideOutVertically { it }
) {
   SomeComposable()
}
```

Also, there is a good scheme of how to select suitable animation in Jetpack Compose: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation

Answer (score 2):

Just chipping in to the discussion. As others have said, using the `offset` modifier is the quickest way to apply some translation to an element.

However, the `offset` modifier only affects the content being displayed and not the actual size measurement of the element.
If you are offsetting an element `A` based on which another element `B` is positioned, the position of element `B` will remain unchanged regardless of the `.offset` applied to element `A`. This usually means you will be left with  some empty space.
To address this issue, one could apply actual *translation* using the `.graphicsLayer { translationY = translationYPx }` *modifier*.

To sum up, use the `.offset` *modifier* whenever possible as it is much more efficient and only resort to `.graphicsLayer` when you need the size of the element to also change as it goes offscreen for example.

Comment: Yeah i was actually looking for that kind of reply rightly explained thanks V Micran

Answer (score 1):

Using the offset was my solution as well. However used animateDpAsState instead. There a tab indicator is moved on the x axis:

```
val offsetState = animateDpAsState(targetValue = targetPositionDp)
Box(modifier = Modifier
        .offset(offsetState.value, 0.dp)
        .background(color = Color.Red)
        .size(tabWidth, tabHeight))
```